# How can I change a secret Gist to public?

Tags: gist

I've uploaded a `Github Gist` and I've set it to be `secret`.

Now I want to change the gist to `public`, but I can't find how to set it public.

Could anyone help me about that?

Comment: See http://chris.dzombak.name/blog/2011/05/making-private-gist-public.html

Comment: I found this question useful.  Why was it closed?  Programmers are the intended audience, and applying Undolog's answer definitely requires a programmer's skillset. Can anyone suggest a more appropriate Q&A site than stackoverflow for this question to be posted to?  If not, I'd argue that's further evidence that stackoverflow is indeed the appropriate forum.  @mitch-wheat

Comment: Because it is more suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FerretallicA How so? [programmers.se] is for *conceptual questions about software development*. [so] includes [questions about] *software tools commonly used by programmers*.

Comment: "Closed as off topic" begs to differ.

Comment: You can nominate it for reopening by clicking on the reopen link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: It is possible to switch visibility for a Gist now (May 2014). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23575535/6309).

Answer (score 103):

> I upload a Gist code and set it to be secret.
> Now I want to change the gist to public, but I can't find how to set it public.

Since May, 9th 2014, it is possible: "[**Change the visibility of your Gists**](https://github.com/blog/1837-change-the-visibility-of-your-gists)"

> You can change the visibility of your Gists whenever you want.
>
> When editing a Gist you'll now notice a **new option to toggle the visibility between Public and Secret**.
> The URL for your Gist will never change, just its visibility.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/222/2894242/b9be0cd4-d550-11e3-91e8-415b178fb561.gif]

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720678/how-can-i-change-a-secret-gist-to-public/51978714#comment63922423_23575535) by [GiDo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53338/gido) though, since 2016:

> you can only make public a gist that was previously private.
> **When it is public it will stay public**.

This is confirmed in "[Creating gists](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/editing-and-sharing-content-with-gists/creating-gists)"

> After creating a gist, you cannot convert it from public to secret.

Comment: @Muhammad it is best to ask a new question here on Stack Overflow: you will have the help of many Java specialists that way.

Comment: @VonC How is your gif made? Is there any convenient softwares for that?

Comment: @cwhy this one is from the GitHub site. But if I had to guess, I would say https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gifgrabber/id668208984?mt=12 (Mac) or https://screentogif.codeplex.com/ (Windows)

Comment: You have to know that you cannot convert your public Gist into a secret Gist (only Public -> Secret). See https://help.github.com/articles/creating-gists/#creating-a-gist

Comment: @GiDo "you cannot convert your public Gist into a secret Gist (only Public -> Secret)" isn't that the same? "public Gist into a secret" and "Public -> Secret".

Comment: @VonC my bad, I wanted to write "(only Secret -> Public)". So basically you can only make public a gist that was previously private. When it is public it will stay public.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:**

You can still convert a secret gist to a public gist by first selecting "Edit" -> "Make Public". This feature has been partially [rolled back](https://blog.github.com/2014-05-09-change-the-visibility-of-your-gists/), however, since 12/15/16 and you will no longer be able to switch it back to secret.

From the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/):

> After creating a gist, you cannot convert it from public to secret.

Comment: Why on Earth would they do such a thing?

Comment: @JonathanWood I've no idea, but they must've had a good reason.

Comment: Can we delete them instead?

Comment: Probably because the gist id is always the same, and secret gists aren't really secret, just hidden, so the formerly-public gist could still be accessed by id for anyone with a link. That said, it's not like this change truly protects gists either way, just makes it a little less easy to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 9):

Correction; this information is outdated.  See VonC's answer from May 9, 2014.

Original answer:

No, you'll have to create a new public gist and copy/paste the contents.

If you want to preserve all of the *history* of the original secret gist, Chris Dzombak has written [an article walking you through how to clone a gist, step-by-step](http://www.dzombak.com/blog/2011/05/making-private-gist-public.html), to preserve its change history.